# How add stub in the test?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

There is a method that needs to be tested:

```
void DATA::setData(QString path)
{
...........................
    QDir dir(path);
    if (dir.exists()) {
        ...................
    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow put a stub on dir.exists () so that there is a return true when the setData method is called in the test regardless of the change path?

P.S. I use Google Mock and Google Test.

Comment: It's possible to mock library classes with Google Mock. You need to create QDir mock class and then implement exists() method to return what you want in specific situation. Maybe this link helps you forward: http://alexott.net/en/cpp/CppTestingIntro.html#gmock-example

Answer (score 0):

QDir class doesn't have any virtual methods, therefore it is quite difficult to mock it. You can do the trick mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods), but it forces you to use templates. Other way to do it (I would do it like this) is to define additional interface for QDir:

```
class MyAbstractQDirInterface {
public:
    MyAbstractQDirInterface() = default;
    virtual ~MyAbstractQDirInterface() = default;
    virtual bool exists() = 0;
};

class MyConcreteQDirInterface: public MyAbstractQDirInterface {
public:
    MyConcreteQDirInterface() = default;
    ~MyConcreteQDirInterface() override = default;
    bool exists() override {
        // here call the real QDir::exists
    }
};

class MyQDirInterfaceMock: public MyAbstractQDirInterface {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(exists, bool());
};
```

and slightly change the `setData` signature to accept the pointer (or reference, if you prefer) to the `MyAbstractQDirInterface` class:

```
void DATA::setData(MyAbstractQDirInterface* qdirInterface)
{
    // ...
    if (qdirInterface->exists()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the production you can call this method with `MyConcreteQDirInterface` and in test env you can call it with `MyQDirInterfaceMock`.